# Publishing ASP.net to Azure VM

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-virtual-machine

There is LOTS of information on publishing asp to Azure Cloud Web Service and so forth but I cannot find a lot on publishing it to an azure VM.

Also another problem is anything I find assumes I have started a project with azure enabled from the start. Which I haven't done, so I would have to somehow convert it, again I have seen many ways of doing this on the web based on different requirements.

So how would I publish an ASP.net project (that has no reference to azure) to an azure VM.

Thanks

Comment: Once you have complied your application and published it to a directory on your computer, you could simply RDP into your VM and copy files from your computer to a target directory on the VM (CTRL+C/CTRL+V rocks!!! :)). Give it a try.

Comment: So i wouldnt need to specially configure my asp.net? apart from any sql connection strings ofc

Comment: AFAIK no ... publishing to VM is more or less the same process as you would do on your on-premises servers.

Comment: Do tell here how it went!

Comment: Went well ish dude. I got the site to run nicely. However im looking into sorting out my sql database as i cant seem to connect to it in order to publish. But that is another question lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Web Deploy into your VM and publish directly through Visual Studio

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy